# Nonhomeomorphic subsets of the plane

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to find two compact, nonhomeomorphic subsets of the plane, say $X$ and $Y$, such that $X \times [0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $Y \times [0,1]$. I can not think of how a homeomorphism arises when you product with the interval.

Comment: +1 Interesting question. Out of curiosity: why do you ask for compact sets? Do you know an example for non-compact ones?

Comment: The closest example I have found is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26404): Let $X$ be the torus with a hole and $Y$ be a disc with two holes. Then $X \times [0,1] \approx Y \times[0,1]$ as  they are both solids in $\Bbb R^3$ bounded by a sphere with two handles. However for obvious reasons $X$ is not a subset of the plane...

Answer (score 5):

This CW answer is supposed to kick this question from the unanswered queue. I strictly follow the approach mentioned in [What to do with questions that are exact duplicates from MathOverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/what-to-do-with-questions-that-are-exact-duplicates-from-mathoverflow)

---

> There are indeed counterexamples to which Igor Belegradek gave a reference. Here is another counterexample in the plane, perhaps the simplest there is: Let $X$ be an annulus with one arc attached to one of its boundary components and another arc attached to the other boundary component, and $Y$ -  an annulus with two disjoint arcs attached to the same one of its boundary components.

[image]

---

The above answer is written by @WlodekKuperberg

MO link: [Is it true that $X\times I\sim Y\times I\implies X\sim Y$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260953/is-it-true-that-x-times-i-sim-y-times-i-implies-x-sim-y/260963#260963)